# How to reduce the size of parse-server docker image after installing node modules

Tags: docker, npm-install, parse-server

The latest official [parse-server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/parseplatform/parse-server) no longer contains S3 File Adapter according to this [post](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/7324). So I am creating a new image. My Dockerfile -

```
FROM parseplatform/parse-server

USER root

WORKDIR /parse-server

RUN npm install --save @parse/s3-files-adapter

USER node
```

After building -

```
docker build -t my_parse .
```

The resulting docker image is twice the size of the original image.

```
# docker images -a
REPOSITORY                   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
my_parse                     latest    763968cef685   21 seconds ago       565MB
<none>                       <none>    1e92933e370e   23 seconds ago       565MB
<none>                       <none>    8778c6ebc0f7   About a minute ago   247MB
<none>                       <none>    46a2805beb06   About a minute ago   247MB
parseplatform/parse-server   latest    0492a55f2c59   24 hours ago         247MB
```

How do I reduce the size of *my_parse* image and also get rid of the *none* images?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your `npm install` command results in all the dependencies being downloaded, which means that your image includes all the `node_modules` as well, hence the large size.

One possible solution to this problem is to use a [Multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). This way, in your first stage you'll run `npm install`, gather all the files that you need, in order to have your application running and in the second stage you'll only copy those files that are needed, which will result in an overall lighter image.

To delete all the layers that are not used, try running `docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true")`. You can read a bit more about this [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try docker rmi with dangling true, but the layers are dependent. Multi-stage build seems to be the solution as done [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/Dockerfile). But, I am not sure what all needs to be copied. Sorry, I am new to Docker as well as Node.

Comment: If they are dependent, then you're alright. You need those layers, so you should not try to delete them (unless you want to delete the original image, that they depend on). Well, in most cases running `npm install` usually produces something like a `dist` directory, and usually all you need is there. My best guess is that you should try to avoid copying `node_modules` in your final image. Observe what new directories appear once you run `npm install` and experiment. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following Dockerfile builds a smaller docker image -

```
FROM parseplatform/parse-server as initial

USER root

RUN npm install --save @parse/s3-files-adapter

# Release stage
FROM parseplatform/parse-server

USER root

RUN rm package*.json && rm -rf node_modules

COPY --from=initial /parse-server/package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --production --ignore-scripts

USER node
```

But, it is not as small as building directly from the source.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server
$ cd parse-server
$ npm install --save @parse/s3-files-adapter
$ docker build --tag parse-server .
```